# Spring Post Controller always receives null

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a controller as follows, but it always receives null.

```
@ResponseBody
      @RequestMapping(value="/saveAllData", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "text/plain")
      @Override
      public String getAll(String jsonInput) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          System.out.println(jsonInput);
          return jsonInput;
    }
```

The java script call is as follows

```
$.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost:9090/saveAllData",
        type:"POST", 
        contentType: "text/plain",
        data: "Hi", //To avoid making query String instead of JSON
        success: function(resposeJsonObject){
            alert(resposeJsonObject);
}});
```

Spring controller always returns "null". This may be because it receives "null" in "jsonInput" parameter. Can anyone help solve this issue

Comment: Tag your parameter with [`@RequestBody`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody).

Comment: @approxiblue - Thanks a lot. i worked  :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate the method parameter with [`@RequestBody`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody), so Spring knows the parameter should be given the value of the HTTP request body.

Answer (score 0):

Add @RequestBody

```
  @ResponseBody
  @RequestMapping(value="/saveAllData", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "text/plain")
  @Override
  public String getAll(@RequestBody String jsonInput) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      System.out.println(jsonInput);
      return jsonInput;
}
```